# Create Tables for Multi-valued attributes

Tags: sql, database-design, mysqli, foreign-keys

I have one table "`DEPARTMENT`" which has multi locations. I create another table for locations "`DEPARTMENT_LOCATIONS`".

Note that "`Dnumber`" is primary key for `DEPARTMENT` and I want to use the same key inside "`DEPARTMENT_LOCATIONS`".

Is my code right or wrong? and how I can fix it?

```
create table if not exists DEPARTMENT(
    Dname varchar(100) not null,
    Dnumber int unsigned not null,
    primary key (Dnumber)
);
create table if not exists DEPARTMENT_LOCATIONS(
    Location nvarchar(1000) not null default'',
    Dnumber int unsigned not null references DEPARTMENT(Dnumber) on delete cascade,
    primary key (Dnumber)
);
```

Comment: Mysql has nvarchar?And both dnumbers should not have unsigned.

Comment: Should I use int unsigned for both or nvarchar?

Comment: I thought use unsigned is for positive only

Comment: You are correct,you can make them both unsigned.Problem is both columns, when you use a foreign key, have to have the same attributes.

Answer (score 1):

From what you stated, a department can have multiple locations.  If you attempt to set your dnumber as the primary key on both departments and locations, then location would inherently have a 1 to 1 relationship with departments rather than your intended 1 to many - as primary keys have to be unique.

You can still reference the DNumber as your FK, but you would want a separate primary key.  Either a unique int (similar to how you're doing for department), or perhaps a composite key between Dnumber and location.  I'm not personally a fan of composite keys, so i would generally just do an auto increment number in this instance.

Something like this:

```
create table if not exists DEPARTMENT(
    Dname varchar(100) not null,
    Dnumber int unsigned not null,
    primary key (Dnumber)
);

create table if not exists DEPARTMENT_LOCATIONS(
    Location nvarchar(1000) not null default'',
    Dnumber int unsigned not null,
    myKey int unsigned not null,
    primary key (myKey),
    foreign key(Dnumber) references DEPARTMENT (Dnumber) on delete cascade
);
```

Note that i'm not familiar enough with mysql to know the syntax for identity columns as I'm a MS SQL guy, though the concept of the above answer should still hold true.

Answer (score 0):

The columns `Dnumber` must have the same datatype.

```
create table if not exists DEPARTMENT_LOCATIONS(
    Location nvarchar(1000) not null default'',
    Dnumber int unsigned not null,
    primary key (Dnumber),
    foreign key(Dnumber) references DEPARTMENT (Dnumber) on delete cascade
);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af4c0